# Connect 4 game purely out of for loops and list assignments

Tags: python

I'm building a Connect 4 game, but the assignment requires us to build it using for loops for the playing Board and lists for holding player's moves.
I've built the playing Board as follows using for loops;

```py
def drawBoard (field):
    for column in range(7):
            for row in range(15):
                if row % 2 == 0:
                    if row != 14:
                        print("|", end="")
                    else:
                        print("|")
                else:
                    print(field[column][row], end="")
```

Then the Board containing the list items i built as Board;

```py
Board = [["0", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X"],
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", "0", "X", "X", " ", "X"],
         [" ", " ", "X", "0", "0", " ", " "],
         ["0", " ", "X", "0", "0", " ", "0"]]

drawBoard(Board)
```

My issue arises when i try to draw the the Board using the function,
such as;

```
| | |a|Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam Steve\PycharmProjects\moshcourse\pythontest2.py", line 34, in <module>
    drawBoard(Board)
  File "C:\Users\Adam Steve\PycharmProjects\moshcourse\pythontest2.py", line 31, in drawBoard
    print(field[column][row], end="")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can i display the items in the lists into the Board that i drew using the function??
Expected output is,
|0| | | | | |X|
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |
| | |0|X|X| |X|
| | |X|0|0| | |
|0| |X|0|0| |0|

Just as it appears on the Board list but now drawn using the function.

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: Please add more details to your problem along with the code blocks and errors

Comment: You are trying to print `field[column][row]` where `row` values can vary between 0-14. But the list of list i.e. `board` does not have that many entries. So that is why you are getting an error. Same for `column`. Also I think your use of `row` and `column` is opposite of the actual thing.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Your board is 6X7 but you treat it as 7X15. Also please note that indexing as `field[x][y]`, `x` is the row and `y` is the column so your indexing is opposite according to your variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in kuro's comment, your `board` does not have that many entries, for `column`, `range(7)` for 7 items but you have only 6, for `row`, `range(15)` for 15 items but you have only 7, so the IndexError raised. It's also true that you better swap `row` and `column` for their true meaning.

I swap `row` and `column` variables and perform some small changes (see comment in code):

```
def drawBoard(field):
    # range(6) for 6 rows
    for row in range(6):
        for column in range(15):
            if column % 2 == 0:
                if column != 14:
                    print("|", end="")
                else:
                    print("|")
            else:
                # divide the column value by 2, so all odd values can correctly match to 0-7
                print(field[row][column//2], end="")
```

But I suggest to get value directly instead of by index in this case:

```
def draw_board(field):
    for row in field:
        for column in row:
            # print | before each column value
            print("|" + column, end="")
        # print | after reading all column values
        print("|")
```

Output from both code is the same:

```
|0| | | | | |X|
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |
| | |0|X|X| |X|
| | |X|0|0| | |
|0| |X|0|0| |0|
```